# How to write a helper method in ruby to reduce code duplication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm really new to ruby and tbh even programming. I'm trying to use the following code in order to perform the same operation for multiple flavors as follows using a switch case -

```
def Icecream
...
...
Value = case flavors
         when 'STRAWBERRY'
         (shop.straw * 1000).round(5)
         when 'CHOCOLATE'
         (shop.choc * 1000).round(5)
         when 'VANILLA'
         (shop.van * 1000).round(5)
         when 'MANGO'
         (shop.man * 1000).round(5)
         end
...
...
end
```

How can I create a helper method to reduce the code duplication? This maybe a silly question but would be really helpful for learning. Thanks in advance!

So, shop.straw gets me a double value which I'm multiplying with 1000 and rounding.

Comment: You might want to provide more information--this could be a situation where your fundamental data structures should be improved to avoid the awkward `case` situation from the get-go. Also, doubles/floats are inaccurate--it's safest to use integers for prices.

Answer (score 3):

I would do thow things: Extract code into a helper method and using a hash instead of the case block:

```
FLAVORS = { 
  'STRAWBERRY' => :straw, 'CHOCOLATE' => :choc, 'VANILLA' => :van, 'MANGO' => :man 
}.freeze

def do_math(flavor)
  (flavor * 1000).round(5)
end
```

with those two preparations you can set the value like this:

```
value = do_math(shop.public_send(FLAVORS[flavors]))
```

Comment: I'm getting Dynamic Constant Assignment following this way

Comment: Also, can you please suggest where to place the mapping of FLAVORS can be done? Outside the method where I'm using ```value = do_math(shop.public_send(FLAVORS[flavors]))
``` or inside of it

Comment: Constants like `FLAVORS` should be defined only once and should not be re-assigned or changed later. Therefore, you get an error when you put it in a method because then it would be reassigned each time the method is called. Just place is at the top of your class (in the class not above) or script.

Comment: Can you please explain the syntax that's being used with `=>` operator ?

Comment: This seems too clever. Can't we just use `'STRAWBERRY' => shop.straw` directly and skip the `public_send` hackiness? If the price can change, the class should probably be responsible for both "doing the math" (a method) and possibly the hash management to convert strings to method names. OP may have a design problem that should be solved with correct data structure design rather than metaprogramming tricks.

Comment: @anyonymousgamer That is just a normal Ruby hash, with the keys being strings and values being symbols.

Comment: @ggorlen Depends on the context. But if we used `shop.straw` in the hash directly, then the value would only be set once with the values from one specific shop when the hash is initialized. In the case, we would not be able to change the value of `shop.straw` dynamically later or return values from a different `shop`.

Comment: Sure, but that should be OP's first approach if the spec permits it (it's unclear). If we need to meet the requirements you state in the comment, I'd just use a function or a hash or lambdas rather than resorting to metaprogramming right away.

Comment: @ggorlen When the specs are unclear, like in this question, I prefer the code in my answers to work in more cases I can think of. Otherwise, my answer might only work under very special assumptions and would not be helpful to any other developer in the future.

Comment: That's cool, but again, no need for metaprogramming, as I mentioned.

Comment: @ggorlen I get your point. But in your function, you calculate possible return values when initializing the hash for a given shop, just to pick one of them. The does feel very efficient to me. I think it is better to only calculate the specific value we need. But again: The question and the use-case is not clear. Without more context we are just guessing what might be the best way.

Comment: Yep, that's the downside of having a hash in a function, but I added 2 alternate versions that mitigate this problem, still without metaprogramming. Anyway, there's some quote I heard from some Dijkstra fellow about premature optimization--I doubt the hash creation is the bottleneck of the app and we should probably just use it until proven otherwise rather than jumping straight into anything fancy.

Comment: That's the good thing about StackOverflow: People will provide different solutions, with different pros and cons. Depending on their context and requirements, the readers can choose what fits best for them.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a couple of things. The easiest solution would probably be one that takes the "double value" as an argument like so:

```
def calculation(flavor)
  (flavor * 1000).round(5)
end
```

Then, your case statement would be:

```
Value = case flavors
        when 'STRAWBERRY'
          calculation(shop.straw)
        when 'CHOCOLATE'
          calculation(shop.choc)
        when 'VANILLA'
          calculation(shop.van)
        when 'MANGO'
          calculation(shop.man)
        end
```

You could probably simply it further if you needed, but that's the main idea.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I have a silly doubt.. So, this helper method should be declared inside the method Icecream or outside of the method?

Comment: You'd want it outside, in the same context (whether it is a module or class), whatever the parent is.

Comment: So, outside of method Icecream somewhere in the same class?

Comment: Yep! If you're not going to use it anywhere else, it may not be a bad idea to throw it under a `private` so that other classes don't have access to it; but that's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

The method suggested by [moyeradon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4400698/moyeradon) could be paired with another refactor as well

```rb
value = calculation(shop.flavor_value(flavor))
```

with Shop having a method that now handles the flavors

```rb
def flavor_value(flavor)
  flavor_sym = flavor.downcase.to_sym

  # Then call the desired logic to get the values being returned by the straw, chocolate, van, man methods here
end
```

This way Icecream doesn't know about individual flavors and as the flavors change you don't need to update Icecream.

Comment: Thank you! May I know what does calculate represent ? I don't find it defined anywhere ?

Comment: Also what does   flavor_sym = flavor.downcase.to_sym represent?

Comment: Calculate came from moyeradon's solution, I will edit to make it more consistent with that.

Comment: [parameterize](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/5.0.0.1/String:parameterize) may be a better alternative with the `_` separator argument to `downcase` as it would handle multi word flavors like `Mint Chocolate Chip`

'Mint Chocolate Chip'.parameterize(separator: "_").to_sym => :mint_chocolate_chip
 
the `to_sym` converts the string into a symbol, which is preferred for hash keys and has [advantages and disadvantages to a string](http://www.randomhacks.net/2007/01/20/13-ways-of-looking-at-a-ruby-symbol/)

Comment: flavor_sym = flavor.downcase.to_sym is a suggestion to normalizing the flavor argument. Down the road you may want to accept 'STRAWBERRY', 'Strawberry' and 'strawberry' as the same value. this code would convert all of those into :strawberry. Giving you more flexibility and not needing to make a lot of changes to the code for accepting casing differences. Its unlikely, but 'StrAWberrY' would also work with code like this in place.

Comment: I think it would be more clear to understand if the solution is completed :) Can you also fill in the part that was written in comment section #

Comment: the commented section is where your logic behind `shop.straw` and the rest of the flavors gets handled in / by what ever `shop` is.

The idea that I am trying to get across is [the Law of Demeter](https://devblast.com/b/rails-delegate-dont-break-the-law-of-demeter)

Answer (score 0):

[spickermann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74485102/6243352) has the right idea of using a hash, but goes a bit awry with the unnecessary `public_send` in my opinion. There's no need to bring metaprogramming into the situation. Much cleaner is to put the shop values directly into the hash, which removes the symbol and `public_send` steps.

```rb
flavor_to_price = {
  'STRAWBERRY' => shop.straw,
  'CHOCOLATE' => shop.choc,
  'VANILLA' => shop.van,
  'MANGO' => shop.man
}

p (flavor_to_price[flavors] * 1000).round(5)
```

Here's a complete example that uses a mock-up `Shop`:

```rb
class Shop
  attr_reader :straw, :choc, :van, :man

  def initialize
    @straw = 1 # made up prices
    @choc = 2
    @van = 3
    @man = 4
  end
end

shop = Shop.new
flavor_to_price = {
  'STRAWBERRY' => shop.straw,
  'CHOCOLATE' => shop.choc,
  'VANILLA' => shop.van,
  'MANGO' => shop.man
}

# called 'flavors' in your code, but singular makes more sense
flavor = 'MANGO'

p (flavor_to_price[flavor] * 1000).round(5) # => 4000
```

If you don't want the hash to be associated with a shop or need to handle price changes at runtime, another option that avoids metaprogramming is to use a function:

```rb
def flavor_to_price(shop, flavor)
  {
    'STRAWBERRY' => shop.straw,
    'CHOCOLATE' => shop.choc,
    'VANILLA' => shop.van,
    'MANGO' => shop.man
  }.fetch flavor
end

flavor = 'MANGO'
shop = Shop.new

p (flavor_to_price(shop, flavor) * 1000).round(5) # => 4000
```

That said, you may have an underlying design problem or two. The flavor-to-price hash should probably be controlled by the class itself rather than existing as an external case/switch/branch or data structure, as suggested by [SMAG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74484677/6243352).

Class properties aren't great substitutes for hash mappings when you're simply listing name-price relationships. Let's say you had 200 flavors. That'd be data you'd want to represent in something closer to a JSON primitive such as a string -> number hash rather than class properties. I don't see that 4 flavors would be different.

Less related, but I'd make the prices integers rather than floats, which have precision issues. Add the decimal in for display purposes, not business logic.

This is all a bit speculative since you may be a client of `Shop` and are bound to work with its existing API.

---

Here are a couple of other alternatives for comparison. If you really don't want to incur the hash allocation cost for the above function-based version (probably premature optimization), lambdas are possible:

```rb
# ...
flavor_to_price = {
  'STRAWBERRY' => lambda {|shop| shop.straw},
  'CHOCOLATE' => lambda {|shop| shop.choc},
  'VANILLA' => lambda {|shop| shop.van},
  'MANGO' => lambda {|shop| shop.man}
}

flavor = 'MANGO'
shop = Shop.new

p (flavor_to_price[flavor].(shop) * 1000).round(5) # => 4000
```

Another option is to use a closure over the shop so we only incur the hash allocation once per shop:

```rb
def make_flavor_to_price_translator(shop)
  prices = {
    'STRAWBERRY' => shop.straw,
    'CHOCOLATE' => shop.choc,
    'VANILLA' => shop.van,
    'MANGO' => shop.man
  }
  Proc.new {|flavor| prices.fetch flavor}
end

shop = Shop.new
flavor = 'MANGO'
flavor_to_price = make_flavor_to_price_translator(shop)

p (flavor_to_price[flavor] * 1000).round(5) # => 4000
```

The above two approaches have obvious readability tradeoffs so I'm not necessarily recommending them without more context.